# json to text converts int to wrong text value

Tags: postgresql

I have a strange json problem that happens when i want to convert an int value to text.
Instead of converting it 1:1 its formating the text.

This is the select:

```
select i.id, 
json -> 'shipper' as shipper,
json -> 'shipper'->>'phone' as phoneNumber
from doc.incident i
join doc.report r on r.incident_id=i.id and schema=2
where i.id=1116
```

It returns this:
[image]

As you can see it formatted the int value in a strange way.

This is weird because i cant reproduce this behaviour. If i would construct the conversion like this:

```
select '{"refnumber":9292929,"phone":12312398892}'::json->>'phone' as phoneNumber
```

It does return it correctly:

[image]

I tried converting it back and forth with text but it always seems to happen when i postgres is trying to convert the int value to text.

One thing to mention is that the type of the phonenumber field changed over the years. It seems that very old records have an int saved while most modern one have a text stored. Maybe that mix between two different datatypes has something to do with it. However i need to extract them as text

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this.

Also. It seems when i cast the text value from json to double and then back to text it also seems to work. So i suspect it is somewhere a problem with the conversion when retrieving it from json:

[image]

Comment: can you share in full text mode the complete json which fails ? In your select clause, is 'json' a column of the `doc.incident` table or the `doc.report` table ?

Comment: json is a json column in doc.report

Comment: the `phoneNumber` value seems to be interpreted as a numeric value before the conversion into text. Can you please share in full text mode the complete json which fails ?

Comment: please understand that the full object contains business data i dont want to share. However you can see the subset it is running on called shipper in my screenshot which contains the json it uses

Comment: What is the client you are using to view the output? It is not Postgres doing the conversion: `select '{"refnumber":9292929,"phone":12312398892}'::json->>'phone' as phoneNumber; 12312398892`, `select pg_typeof('{"refnumber":9292929,"phone":12312398892}'::json->>'phone') as phoneNumber; text`.

Comment: i am using pgadmin

Comment: Pretty sure this is a `pgAdmin` issue. What do you see when you run the query in `psql`?

Comment: i am afraid thats not the case. I run two queries in pgadmin and they return different results. also we noticed the same result during our report generation with BIRT. So i am quit sure its postgres

Comment: You still have not said what happens when you run the query in `psql`? Have no idea what BIRT is?

Comment: Which version are you using? Is your `json` column of `JSON` type or `JSONB` type?

Comment: the json column is of type JSON

Comment: If you do `SELECT i.id, (json -> 'shipper')::TEXT as shipper FROM doc.incident i JOIN doc.report r on r.incident_id=i.id and schema=2 WHERE i.id=1116`, does the number also show in scientific notation with an `E`?

Comment: i have tested this also and yes it does. its also doing it for the refnumber btw

Comment: In what client you seen the scientific notation? I cannot replicate your output in either `psql` or `pgAdmin`. This is not normal behavior. Where did you install Postgres from and what version?  What is `lc_numeric` set to in your Postgres instance? Has anyone been modifying the JSON operators? Extensions installed that may have done this? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Which versions of PostgreSQL and pgAdmin are you using, btw?

Comment: As screenshot indicates. Both happening in Pgadmin. As well as in BIRT using jdbc. Thats why i suspect a problem in postgres. I am using postgres 11 and pgadmin 2

Comment: I made an update to my question. I forgot to mention that we have json records where int is stored and records where text is stored. Maybe that is causing it

Comment: There is no `pgAdmin 2`. One more time please show the result of the query `select i.id, ...` when run in `psql`. Also in `psql` a select that shows the different values for `shipper ->> phone`. This will take the client libraries(`pgAdmin` and `Java`) out of the mix and show what is in the database proper. Add as update to your question. Without this information you will get only guesses not a full answer.

Comment: Try: `...json -> 'shipper' -> 'phone' as phoneNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that for some reason, the JSON was stored using scientific notation in the first place (which is valid).

Essentially, whatever imported that JSON data into your database in the first place sent the JSON using scientific notation.

It's possible that tool that displayed your `shipper` JSON value in the first place actually parsed and re-serialised that JSON itself.

One way to extract this data correctly would be to convert it into numbers and then into text, using something like this:

```sql
CASE WHEN content->>'x' LIKE '%E%'
     THEN (content->>'x')::NUMERIC::TEXT
     ELSE content->>'x'
END
```

The reason I'm checking whether the text contains `E` in the first place is that you might not want to lose `0` at the start of the phone numbers for the entries that would be text.

Here is an example to see the differences:

```sql
WITH vals(id, content) AS (VALUES
    (1::INT, '{"x":12312398892}'::JSON),
    (2::INT, '{"x":1.2312398892E10}'),
    (3::INT, '{"x":"01234567"}')
) 
SELECT id,
       content,
       content->>'x',
       (content->>'x')::NUMERIC::TEXT,
       CASE WHEN content->>'x' LIKE '%E%'
            THEN (content->>'x')::NUMERIC::TEXT
            ELSE content->>'x'
       END
FROM vals;
```

| id | JSON | Extracted field | `::NUMERIC::TEXT` | Handling with/without E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"x":12312398892} | 12312398892 | 12312398892 | 12312398892 |
| 2 | {"x":1.2312398892E10} | 1.2312398892E10 | 12312398892 | 12312398892 |
| 3 | {"x":"01234567"}" | 01234567 | 1234567 | 01234567 |

Comment: Except the screen shot that shows the result of `json -> 'shipper' as shipper,` displays `"phone":12312398892`, so it is not being stored as scientific notation.

Comment: That's what I'm saying: the tool that loaded it could have de-serialised it when loading and re-serialised it for display. Something based on `psycopg2` would be likely to do that by default. If it's pgAdmin, it could very much depend on the version since it moves quite quickly.

Comment: No `psycopg2` does not do that: `cur.execute("select id, fld_json -> 'shipper' -> 'phone' from json_test")  cur.fetchone()  (1, 12312398892)`. Also the OP is seeing this using [BIRT](https://eclipse.github.io/birt-website/) which is Java based.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My point is that if `12312398892` had been initially stored as `1.2312398892E10` in the JSON in the first place, Pyscopg2 would decode it as a number (before the front-end re-stringifying it in the table): `cursor.execute("""SELECT '{"phone":1.2312398892E10}'::JSON"""); cursor.fetchone()` produces `({'phone': 12312398892.0},)`.

Comment: That fact that `(json -> 'shipper')::TEXT` shows the scientific notation suggested the stored JSON was like that when it was imported in the DB in the first place. Unlike JSONB, the JSON type is just text that is valid JSON.

Comment: I am sorry its not stored like that. It is indeed stored as integer

Comment: I made an update to my question. I forgot to mention that we have json records where int is stored and records where text is stored. Maybe that is causing it

Comment: (content->>'x')::NUMERIC::TEXT  would actually work and would solve my problem. BUT my challenge is that the numeric value is only stored on old records. New records have the phone number stored as text. This does fail on records that are text and cant be cast.  If you could maybe incoorporate this it would work

Comment: @user2316219 Your entire JSON content is stored as text in a column of JSON type. I'm talking PostgreSQL types here, not within JSON (JSON is effectively a text serialisation of other types). What I'm also saying, from what you said earlier about the output of `(json -> 'shipper')::TEXT` is that it's likely that it's how the JSON data was serialised before being stored in the DB. `1.2312398892E10` and `12312398892` are two equivalent JSON serialisations of the same integer (although the former doesn't really make sense as a phone number).

Comment: When you use `->>` you always get `TEXT` as a returned type. When you use `->` you'd get JSON. The example I've given you above with the `CASE WHEN ...` should work whether your JSON value is of (JSON) type integer or text.